# Merge curved polygons with Postgis

Tags: postgis

is there any way to merge/union curved polygons in Postgis?

*"SELECT ST_UNION(the_geom) from public.polygons"*  can be executed, if the type of *the_geom* is *Polygon*, but doesn't work with the type *CurvePolygon* ("ERROR: Unknown geometry type: CurvePolygon").

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in, [ST_CurveToLine](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_CurveToLine.html), ie, `SELECT ST_UNION(ST_CurveToLine(the_geom)) from public.polygons`. This converts the CurvePolygon to a Polygon first. You could then use the inverse operation, ST_LineToCurve, to convert back, should you wish to, ie,  `SELECT ST_LineToCurve(ST_UNION(ST_CurveToLine(the_geom))) from public.polygons`